# Create Winforms user control that can accept a DataSource and create children per rows in source?

Tags: winforms, data-binding, user-controls

[image: mockup]

I'm trying to create a user control along the lines of the illustration. Something like a repeater, where there can be an arbitrary number of rows based on the data source, the labels are populated from the data source, and (possibly only tangential to this question) the buttons are enabled/disabled based on the whether the fields in the data source are null or not.

My first such user control would be job tracker where you can have multiple jobs in progress, and you click the buttons to record progress per job, but I have other layouts in mind for other tasks, too.

I already know all about DataTables and DataAdapters, so I can populate a table and plug that in to the user control's DataSource property. The user control should modify the in-memory DataTable and I can later sync that back upstream with a DataAdapter Update().

1. (Most important) How does the user control know what to do with the DataSource you feed it? I tried looking at the stock DataGridView's code in ILSpy, but it was a bit too hairy to be helpful. I did spend a whole day Googling this, but user control data binding is a bit vague for web searches and most examples were too simplistic (i.e. binding a single textbox, rather than genrating and populating multiple controls).
2. (Less important) Is nesting user controls two deep the way to go to achieve the scrolling? Outer user control having a FlowLayoutPanel that contains several instances of inner user controls with the labels/buttons? (This is how I mocked up the screenshot.)

Comment: Are you looking for [`DataRepeater`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488280.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: Your question are not related to each other, it's better to post your second question in a new post. [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/308647)

Comment: @RezaAghaei : It crossed my mind, but that complicates deployment since it's not a stock .net assembly. Maybe as a last resort.

Comment: It's a standard Microsoft control which doesn't need any special strategy for deployment. Just use it and since it would be in you bin directory, your application will work like always with xcopy deployment!

Comment: I actually started out with a DataGridView, but its button functionality was a little too bare bones (can't even disable buttons out of the box) and I want more freedom in arranging the labels to make it more intuitive for users.

Comment: I'll use `DataGridView` for such cases. You can *simply* customize appearance of buttons.

Comment: Look at this example from MSDN: [How to: Disable Buttons in a Button Column in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171619(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0)